# How to insert images into the template in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I want to recode my 1st template from html/css to wordpress but i don't remember how to insert images in php

For example HTML:

```
<img src="img/imageOne.jpg">
```

And PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to user wordpress function like this,

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/imageOne.jpg">
```

Check [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) for more reference.

Comment: @ROCKY : Please do upvote if you got your answer. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1):

images add in WordPress template

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/imageOne.jpg"/>
```